# Overriding Token class in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, inheritance

New to Django, but here goes, in our use case we need token based authentication but require the token to be linked to a model other than the default 'User' model (django.contrib.auth.models.User). Now to do this, we *can* rewrite the Token model/class, or we can inherit the `Token` model and add the new field and set the `user` field to `None` but the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) says

> In Django, this isn’t usually permitted for model fields. If a non-abstract model base class has a field called author, you can’t create another model field or define an attribute called author in any class that inherits from that base class.

But shortly after it says,

> This restriction doesn’t apply to model fields inherited from an abstract model. Such fields may be overridden with another field or value, or be removed by setting field_name = None.

Now if we don't add `rest_framework.authtoken` to `settings.py`, the `Token` class is technically abstract. Since in the source code for `Token`,

```
abstract = 'rest_framework.authtoken' not in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
```

So is it permissible to override the Token class in this way or is it simply better to re-write the model altogether?

Comment: I had a similar situation once and have written custom Token and Authentication classes. It was pretty much copy/paste from DRF source with some changes. Otherwise, when I start a new project, I try to use built-in functionalities as much as possible. There is no point in reinventing the wheel and usually just makes maintenance harder without any real benefit.

Comment: @Borut I agree, but I need Tokens to authenticate devices (multiple devices per user) instead of users. Hence, I'm a bit stuck as to how I should proceed.

Comment: any success ? i've got same issue

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this question is still relevant to you, but for anyone still curious, you should create a subclass of the `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication` class in an `authentication.py` file in your app (`user` in my case) package, like:

```py
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication as BaseTokenAuthentication
from user.models import Token


class TokenAuthentication(BaseTokenAuthentication):
    model = Token
```

here you set your following custom `Token` class from `models.py` as the model:

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token as BaseToken

class Token(BaseToken):
    key = models.CharField(_('Key'), max_length=40, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_token',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('User')
    )
```

And in your project's `settings.py` you set (`user` is my app name):

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'user.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.